# БД для расписания транспорта

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Как правильнее организовать архитектуру базы данных расписания транспорта?

В своем приложении я хочу сделать что-то на подобии этого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом приложение, чтобы дойти до этого экрана мы выбираем сам маршрут автобуса, потом его направление(от нач.остановки и до конечной или наоборот), далее выбираем остановку и любуемся на расписание определенного маршрута на определенной остановке. Особенно мне нравится концепция расписания вида: "час" - "минуты"(которую я хочу реализовать в своем приложении).

Единственное, что до меня дошло сделать, это создать таблицу такого вида для каждого маршрута:

Столбцы:

1)имя остановки (text) **Напр. "Вокзал"**

2)направление(integer, 1 - для направления от нач.остановки до конечной, 0 - для наоборот) **Напр. 1**

3)Часы (text)  **Напр. "15"**

4)Минуты (text) **Напр. "12 14 34 56"**

Таким образом одна строка такой таблицы позволяет узнать о том, что определенный маршрут следуя одному из двух направлений, остановится на определенной остановке в определенный час и определенные минуты.

Таким образом, если я буду заполнять таблицу в таком виде она будет работать, я даже смогу черпать из нее правильные данные и даже смогу сделать что-то на подобии что есть на картинке. Но я точно знаю, что такая БД - неправильная. Первое с чем я столкнулся, это то что мне придется очень долго ее заполнять, учитывая каждое направление, каждый час и так далее.

Я очень пытался объяснить что я сделал, чем недоволен и что хотел бы получить, надеюсь что суть понятна. И под конец вопрос, каким образом можно спроектировать правильную БД под данные критерии? В какую сторону мне копать? А может кто то посоветует уже готовые решения, потому что я уже не раз видел такой механизм расписания в приложениях.

Comment: Правильныого ответа на ваш вопрос не существует.

Comment: Ну может хотя бы какие то наводки да существуют? И что значит правильного ответа не существует?

Comment: означает: как напишете, так и будет правильно.

Comment: Спорно оно как то, ну да ладно.